# Irregular bounding box for text in LaTeX

Tags: bounding-box

[Bounding box example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joKx8.png)

[image]

Can you tell me the package to use to make the irregular shape for bounding the text, as in the example just above ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example image is from the page 16 of the [French initiation to LaTeX by Stéphane Pasquet](https://www.mathweb.fr/euclide/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Initiation-a-LaTeX-de-Stephane-Pasquet.pdf).

The source of the PDF is not available. But his `mathbook` class, available on his website, has [on pages 12-14 of the documentation](https://www.mathweb.fr/euclide/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/mathbook.pdf) a similar border with the mathbook class environment `demonstration`.

The code of `mathbook.cls` is available in [this zipped file](https://www.mathweb.fr/euclide/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/mathbook.zip), and for the `demonstration` environment, precisely in the file `commandes.tex`.

You could then see that the author uses the `TikZ` package and the `decorations.pathmorphing` tikzlibrary, with `random steps`.

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\tikz\node[draw,thick,inner sep=0.25cm,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt, amplitude=1pt}] {{\Large Mon texte en Large} et maintenant en taille normale.};

\end{document}
```

you will obtain:
[image]

Comment: Very clear and precise answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can also draw the randomized box with MetaFun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibsetformat{metafun}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
input rboxes ;

beginfig(0) ;
    numeric amplitude, segment_length, n ;
    path p, q ;

    amplitude := 1pt ;
    segment_length := 3pt ;

    boxit.a("{\Large Mon texte en Large} et maintenant en taille normale.");
    drawunboxed(a);
    p := bpath a ;
    n := arclength p / segment_length ;
    q := for i = 0 upto n: point (i/n) along p -- endfor cycle;
    draw q randomized amplitude ;
endfig ;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So at the end of it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand\randombox[1]{%
\tikz{%
  \node[inner sep=1em,text width=.85\linewidth,align=flush left] (A) {#1};  
  \draw[decoration={random steps,segment length=0.4cm,amplitude=.1cm},decorate]
        (A.north west) -- (A.north east) -- (A.south east) -- (A.south west) -- cycle;
}}

\begin{document}
\randombox{%
    {\Large Mon text en large} mon text
}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the result

[image]

Thanks to samcarter for this code

https://texnique.fr/osqa/users/1702/samcarter